# Integration of volumes of revolution: bisector surface

Tags: integration, volume

> $y = (16-x^2)^{0.5}$ is rotated around the $x$-axis to give a sphere of radius $4$ units. Find the equation of the straight line that passes through $(-4,0)$, such that when also rotated around the $x$-axis, will create a surface that bisects the volume of the sphere.

The equation will obviously take the form $y=kx+4k$. I tried to solve for the volume bounded by the revolutions of the semicircle and the straight line being equal to exactly half the volume of the sphere. The result was a very complicated series of substitutions and expansions which yielded no valid solution (it was a $6^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial with only $1$ positive solution of $2.27$ for $k$, which is quite obviously wrong).

My question is whether there is a simpler, perhaps more ingenious way of finding $k$.

Again, thanks in advance and all contributions welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The volume of your sphere is $\,\displaystyle{\frac43\pi 4^3=\frac{256\pi}{3}}\,$ . You need a line $\,y=kx+4k\,$ ,  which intersects $\,y=\pm\sqrt{16-x^2}\,$ at

$$16-x^2=k^2x^2+8k^2x+16k^2\implies(k^2+1)x^2+8k^2x+16(k^2-1)=0\implies$$

$$\Delta=64k^4-64(k^4-1)=8^2\implies$$

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-8k^2\pm8}{2(k^2+1)}=\begin{cases}\;\;\;\;\;\;-4\\{}\\-\frac{4(k^2-1)}{k^2+1}\end{cases}$$

Thus, we want

$$\pi\int\limits_{-4}^{-\frac{4(k^2-1)}{k^2+1}}(kx+4k)^2x\,dx=\left.\frac\pi{3k}(kx+4k)^3\right|_{-4}^{-\frac{4(k^2-1)}{k^2+1}}=\frac\pi{3k}\frac{8^3k^3}{(k^2+1)^3}=\frac{512k^2\pi}{3(k^2+1)^3}$$

And now we want

$$\frac{2^9k^2\pi}{3(k^2+1)^3}=\frac{2^7\pi}{3}\iff4k^2=(k^2+1)^3$$

and according to WA the resulting sixtic equation doesn't even have any real roots...

Comment: Should you not integrate the cone (which you just did nicely) and the sphere from the intercept to 4, to equal half the volume of sphere?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: I did integrate the cone from $\,-4\,$ to the intersect, and equated the result to half the sphere's volume. My result points towards the fact there's no solution to the problem **when** the cone's vertex is at the extreme of one of the sphere's diameters...or, of course, towards the fact that I made somewhere a mistake. :)

Comment: If by *inscribed* you mean the cone's vertex is on the sphere and its symmetry line is the corresponding diameter, yes: you're right.

Comment: i think your result proves there is no cone inscribed in a sphere with a volume of exactly half the sphere, which makes sense. I think the question asks for only the curvy part of the cone (not the base), which bisects the volume of the sphere. So i think it wants the volume of the cone (which is evaluated by you) plus the volume of the remainder of the sphere, from -4(K^2-1)/(K^2+1) to 4, to equal half of the volume of the sphere.